# Access VBA - prevent duplicate entry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to avoid Access built-in msgbox about entering duplicate records, by checking entries  in before update event. Code works, but one BIG problem - you cannot edit those records anymore. Any way to accomplish both - allow edits and avoid Access msgbox ?

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyTable", dbOpenDynaset)

If Data_Changed Then 'Variable of Boolean that is set to True in Dirty event

     If Not IsNull(ID_Field) Then

         If MsgBox("You have done changes. you wish to save? ?" & vbCrLf & vBCrLf & "Click Yes for saving changes or NO for Undoing changes ! " & _
         , vbQuestion + vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton1) = vbOK Then

             rs.FindFirst "ID = " & Me.ID_Field

             If Not rs.NoMatch Then
                 Cancel = True
                 MsgBox "Error. You cannot add another record with same ID!", vbCritical
                 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
                 Exit Sub
             End If


         Else

             DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo

         End If

      Else

          MsgBox "Error. you cannot save record with blank ID !", vbCritical

          DoCmd.SetWarnings False
          If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo
          DoCmd.SetWarnings True

          Exit Sub

      End If

      Me.ID_Field.Locked = True
      Me.Other_Field.Locked = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I see. Is your `ID_Field` the Primary Key? Normally, PKs should be invisible to the user, and definitely not be editable by the user. As you have found out, it creates problems. If it's the PK, is there a reason why users can edit it? If not, you can use the PK to identify the current record and exclude it from your search.

Comment: @Andre, no. ID_Field is not primary key. And PK is invisible to user.But both ID and ID_Field(which has completety different name - I messed this up) have index set to No duplicates. However, changing Id_Field to Indexed No doesn't change anything.

Comment: How can I exclude record from search, but keep code going If new record with same Id_Field would be entered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your primary key column is `myPK`.

To check `ID_Field` against all but the current record, don't use a Recordset and `FindFirst`, use `DLookup` instead.

```
Dim TestID as Long
TestID = Nz(DLookup("ID_Field", "MyTable", "ID_Field = " & Me.ID_Field & _
                    " AND myPK <> " & Nz(Me.myPK, 0)), 0)
If TestID > 0 Then
    ' Dupe
Else
    ' ok
End If
```

You may need to add `myPK` as invisible text box to the form, to be able to read its value.

Comment: Great Andre, this works !! What a nightmare, I have tried thousand variations but nothing worked. A BIG thanks !

Comment: Andre, what about If need combination of two fields ? like ID_Field and SomeOther_Field ? just add It after Me.ID_Field ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82: The 3rd parameter of DLookup is like a WHERE clause, you can build any criteria you like. e.g. `"ID_Field = " & Me.ID_Field & " AND SomeOther_Field = " & Me.SomeOther_Field & " AND myPK <> " & Nz(Me.myPK, 0)`. For text criteria, enclose them in `''`.

Comment: I have tried this, but seems like it doesn't work :  Nz(DLookup("ID_Field", "JoinTable", "ID_Field = " & Me.ID_Field & Another_Field & _
                    " AND PK_JoinTable <> " & Nz(Me.PK_JoinTable, 0)), 0). However, this is a Join table, and index of 2 FK has to be checked.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82: Build your query in the query design editor, switch to SQL view, and use the WHERE clause as template to build the DLookup parameter.

Comment: I will try, and let you know.

Comment: I don't know - I tried this but It's not working...Problem is that Dlookup's first parameter should be a combination of 2 fields. It's a Join table, from which I need to check duplicates of 2 fields together (both fields are FK). This is too difficult for me.

Comment: I have opened another thread for that, I just can't get It working, It's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

A "snapshot" takes the records in their current state for e.g. inspection. They are read-only.

To open the record set read/write, use `dbOpenDynaset`

Comment: I tried, but this doesn't solve the problem, Records still can't be edited.

Comment: Please show the full code where you try to edit the record(s).

Comment: Paul, my code for editing records is simple button which unlocks the fields in continous form.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the built-in message, it is best to use the `Form.OnError` event.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836345.aspx

E.g. like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    ' Error 3022 = "Cannot add a duplicate value because of a key constraint..."
    If DataErr = 3022 Then
        MsgBox "Your duplicate warning", vbExclamation
        ' Remove duplicate ID and set focus into ID control
        Me!ID_Field = Null
        Me!ID_Field.SetFocus
        ' Dont't show default error message
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    Else
        ' Other errors: show default error message
        Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for that. I allready had something like this before, but still one problem - When you are still on same record in continous form and you try to save record via DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord, error "3022" still pops-up. This can be solved by a simple Error handle - If err.number=3022 Then...However, form error code works when you try to go on another record in continous form. BUT - I'm trying to solve this problem with one code only, that's why I changed everything.